# Mouse pointer stuck as I login

Tags: ubuntu, mouse

As I log into Ubuntu my mouse pointer get stuck. I have tried the following methods:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

I have also tried this:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```

How I can restore my pointer.

I don't face this problem when I log in as a Guest user in Ubuntu, also my mouse starts moving when I attach an external USB mouse.
This is output of my lsmod command

```
    haider@ubuntu:~$ lsmod | sort 
    arc4                   12473  2 
    bcma                   25651  0 
    binfmt_misc            17292  1 
    bluetooth             158447  10 rfcomm,bnep
    bnep                   17830  2 
    brcmsmac              540923  0 
    brcmutil               14675  1 brcmsmac
    cfg80211              178877  2 brcmsmac,mac80211
    cordic                 12518  1 brcmsmac
    crc8                   12781  1 brcmsmac
    dcdbas                 14098  1 dell_laptop
    dell_laptop            17767  0 
    dell_wmi               12601  0 
    drm                   197641  4 i915,drm_kms_helper
    drm_kms_helper         45466  1 i915
    hid                    77428  1 usbhid
    i2c_algo_bit           13199  1 i915
    i915                  428056  8 
    intel_ips              17822  0 
    joydev                 17393  0 
    lp                     17455  0 
    mac80211              436493  1 brcmsmac
    mac_hid                13077  0 
    mei                    36570  0 
    Module                  Size  Used by
    parport                40930  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
    parport_pc             32114  0 
    ppdev                  12849  0 
    psmouse                86520  0 
    r8169                  56396  0 
    rfcomm                 38139  0 
    serio_raw              13027  0 
    snd                    62218  16 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
    snd_hda_codec         109562  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_hda_intel
    snd_hda_codec_hdmi     31775  1 
    snd_hda_codec_idt      60251  1 
    snd_hda_intel          32719  3 
    snd_hwdep              13276  1 snd_hda_codec
    snd_page_alloc         14108  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
    snd_pcm                80916  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
    snd_rawmidi            25424  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_seq                51592  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
    snd_seq_device         14172  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
    snd_seq_midi           13132  0 
    snd_seq_midi_event     14475  1 snd_seq_midi
    snd_timer              28931  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
    soundcore              14635  1 snd
    sparse_keymap          13658  1 dell_wmi
    usbhid                 41937  0 
    uvcvideo               67203  0 
    video                  19115  1 i915
    videodev               86588  1 uvcvideo
    wmi                    18744  1 dell_wmi
```

Comment: Please provide us output from `lsmod`.

Comment: @slm I have edited the question and added the output of my lsmod command.Can you Please identify the module which i need to remove 
Thanks a lot

Comment: @slm Thank You so much for you attention. I finally solved my problem. http://askubuntu.com/questions/65736/touchpad-not-working-on-dell-xps-l501x

Comment: Glad you solved your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an issue with a kernel module. Did you recently install any new updates or drivers? Boot up into single user or text only mode and try to remove your mouse module.

In the console type:

```
lsmod
```

look for a module relating to mouse and trackpad such as `synaptics`, `xf86` or `touchegg`, and then remove them using:

```
sudo modprobe -r module_name
```

then try to re-logon

Comment: can i do it without going GRUB( text only mode)

Comment: @Braiam can i do it without GRUB mode

Comment: @HaiderAli - you should be able to unload this module at any time. Do a `sudo rmmod <module name>` to unload a Kernel module.

Comment: @slm But none of above mentioned module exist in my kernel

Answer (score 0):

> I don't face this problem when I log in as a Guest user

It has to be something in your profile. If you can, try purging any of your `~/.directories` that has to do with Gnome. (Assuming GDM is used.)

Comment: Problem Solved with this answer http://askubuntu.com/questions/65736/touchpad-not-working-on-dell-xps-l501x

Answer (score 0):

## New mouse brand not enabled in XFCE

After installing a new mouse replacing a worn Microsoft™ mouse, I experienced a similar problem on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS. The new mouse would work flawlessly on the LightDM login screen. However, after logging in, the new mouse would not respond at all in the XFCE session.

The problem lied in the fact that the old mouse was known under the device description `Microsoft Basic Optical Mouse`, whereas the new Anker mouse is known simply as `USB Optical Mouse`. The latter happened to be not enabled by default.

The solution consists in plugging in both USB mice simultaneously. Then, using the old mouse, select the new mouse device and enable it in the `Mouse and Touchpad` XFCE menu.

[image: Mouse and Touchpad]